# In Kotlin, is it possible to call a member extension function specifying both the object dispatched to and the receiver? If so, how?

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods

Consider the following example:

```
class C {
    fun ThirdPartyClass.f() {
        // Do stuff involving functions/properties from
        // both the C instance and the ThirdPartyClass receiver
    }

    fun someMethod(third: ThirdPartyClass) {
        // Do stuff...
        third.f()
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Within `C`, there's no problem calling `.f` on a given instance of `ThirdPartyClass`. But outside `C`, given an instance `c` of `C` and an instance `third` of `ThirdPartyClass`, is there a way to invoke `c`'s `f` with `third` as the receiver?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what your `someMethod()` does? It's public so other functions can use it to invoke `f`. There's no syntax for an extension function with multiple receivers, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Tenfour04. Please note that `someMethod()` does other stuff (which might or might not also happen to include calling `f` - that's its own business). I'd like to invoke `f` directly from another piece of code (outside `C`), without relying on `someMethod()`. If that can't be done, is there an authoritative source that states so? I was thinking maybe it's possible to get a reference to the method (`c::f` or something) and then somehow invoke that on `third`. Do we know for a fact there's no way to do that?

Comment: Get the `C` object in scope, then you can call it. This is already used in testing frameworks like [kotest](https://github.com/kotest/kotest), you specify tests like `"name of the test" { /* Test body */ }` where the `""{}` is calling `operator fun String.invoke(block)` defined on that scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: it's possible - see how under ***Solution*** below.

#### Relevant language information

It seems the [spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec) provides relevant information under the [overload resolution](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html) section (more specifically the [receivers](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#receivers) subsection).

From the spec:

> Every function or property that is defined as a method or an extension
> has one or more special parameters called receiver parameters. When
> calling such a callable using navigation operators (. or ?.) the left
> hand side value is called an explicit receiver of this particular
> call. In addition to the explicit receiver, each call may indirectly
> access zero or more implicit receivers.

In other words, a method always has an explicit receiver - which is what will be placed before the `.` when calling it (or not, if it can be used implicitly), and zero or more implicit receivers provided by surrounding scopes (this is explained in greater detail in the spec).

In our example, `f` has an explicit receiver of type `ThirdPartyClass`, and an implicit receiver of type `C`.

Furthermore:

> For extension callables, the receiver used as the extension receiver
> parameter is called extension receiver, while the implicit receiver
> associated with the declaration scope the extension is declared in is
> called dispatch receiver. For a particular callable invocation, any or
> both receivers may be involved, but, if an extension receiver is
> involved, the dispatch receiver must be implicit.

This means there's no way to provide the `C` receiver *explicitly* when calling `f`, as an extension receiver (of type `ThirdPartyClass`) is involved.

#### Solution

But the method can still be called whenever an *implicit* `C` receiver is in scope! This is what happens within other methods of `C` (such as `someMethod` in our example), but it also happens within functions (and lambdas) with a `C` receiver, enabling, e.g.:

```
with (c) { third.f() }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
with (myC) { 
  myThirdPartyClass.f()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Louis - this is indeed one way to do it! I also posted my own answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65376089/777775), providing more information.