# Kotlin: How to explicitly specify the actual type of a lambda?

Tags: java, function, kotlin, lambda, types

How can I explicitly specify the actual type of a lambda in Kotlin?

This is necessary because if I have two functions which take similar lambdas, e.g.

```kotlin
fun use(block: Context.() -> Boolean)
@JvmName("use2") fun use(block: Context.() -> Unit)
```

I'd like to be able to make the `use2` call the regular (Boolean) `use`, i.e.

```kotlin
@JvmName("use2") fun use(block: Context.() -> Unit) = use { block(); true }
```

This is similar to how you can explicitly specify a SAM type, such as:

```kotlin
Runnable { println("hello") }
```

How can I do the same for a Kotlin lambda type?

This is the solution I've come up with how to get around the problem, but I want to know if there's a better/cleaner way.

```kotlin
@JvmName("use2") fun use(block: Context.() -> Unit) = use({ block(); true } as (Context.() -> Boolean)})
```

Comment: I suspect the consensus will be _not_ to allow that confusion in the first place — i.e. not to have two functions with the same name that differ only in the lambda type (and, especially, only in the lambda's _return_ type).  Any way of specifying the type manually will be ugly and awkward, and confusing to read.  Whereas, if you can make the difference clear in the function _name_, you'll avoid all this trouble!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made it work with this:

```
@JvmName("use2") fun use(block: Context.() -> Unit) =
    use({ foo: Context -> block(foo); true } as (Context) -> Boolean)
```

Removing the cast, or the `: String` type annotation will make it not compile. IntelliJ IDEA also wrongly reports that the cast is unnecessary ([note that this isn't the first time IntelliJ is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68427807/how-to-call-invoking-on-a-setter/68428088#68428088))

Note that I've changed the lambda's type from `Context.() -> Boolean` to `(Context) -> Boolean`, because I don't think there is a way to specify the *receiver* type explicitly. This doesn't affect overload resolution though.

If you really want to use something that has a receiver type of `Context`, you can use an anonymous function instead:

```
@JvmName("use2") fun use(block: Context.() -> Unit) =
    use(fun Context.(): Boolean { block(); return true })
```

I think this is a better way of writing `use2`, but note that an anonymous function is different from an lambda [in many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58004914/kotlin-fun-vs-lambda-is-there-difference).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@OverloadResolutionByLambdaReturnType` annotation, but this is an experimental feature, so you need to add `@OptIn(ExperimentalTypeInference::class)`. Also you should specify return type explicitly.

```
fun use(block: Context.() -> Boolean): ReturnType

@OptIn(ExperimentalTypeInference::class)
@OverloadResolutionByLambdaReturnType
@JvmName("use2")
fun use(block: Context.() -> Unit): ReturnType = use { block(); true }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I explicitly specify the actual type of a lambda in Kotlin?

I think there are two options that make the code much more clear: Generics, and functional interfaces. They can also be combined!

### Option 1: Generics (* see update below)

Don't specify the return - use generics instead. We can just have one function for all interactions:

```kotlin
fun <R> use(block: Context.() -> R) : Boolean = context.block()
```

You also want the return to default to `true` if `block` doesn't return a boolean. We can do that too:

```kotlin
fun <R> use(block: Context.() -> R): Boolean {
  // use a 'when' block - it solves type safety issues
  return when (
    val result = context.block() // execute the lambda and store the output in a val
  ) { 
    !is Boolean -> true   // default to 'true' if result is not a boolean
    else        -> result // else, we can return the boolean result of 'block'
  }
}
```

***UPDATE** Actually, generics aren't required as your `use(...)` function always returns Boolean, not the result of the lambda.

Here's a single non-generic `use(...)` function that solves your problem of "two functions with conflicting jvm signatures":

```kotlin
fun  use(block: Context.() -> Any): Boolean {
  // use a 'when' block - it solves type safety issues
  return when (
    val result = context.block() // execute the lambda and store the output in a val
  ) {
    !is Boolean -> true   // default to 'true' if result is not a boolean
    else        -> result // else, we can return the boolean result of 'block'
  }
}
```

### Option 2: Functional interfaces

Use [functional interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html) - it makes the definition of a lambda much more clear and reusable.

```kotlin
// step 1: define our 'lambdas'

// equivalent: Context.() -> Boolean
fun interface ContextPredicate {
  fun Context.execute(): Boolean
}

// equivalent: Context.() -> Unit
fun interface ContextConsumer {
  fun Context.execute()
}

// step 2: define the 'use' functions
class ContextService(
  private val context: Context
) {

  fun use(block: ContextPredicate): Boolean = with(block) {
    context.execute()
  }

  fun use(block: ContextConsumer): Boolean = with(block) {
    context.execute()
    true // default response is 'true' for 'ContextConsumer'
  }
}

// 3. dummy class for testing
data class Context(
  val name: String
)

// 4. test our code
fun main() {
  val service = ContextService(Context("hello"))

  println(
    service.use(ContextPredicate { name == "hello" })
  )
  // output: true

  println(
    service.use(ContextPredicate { name == "good morning" })
  )
  // output: false

  println(
    service.use(ContextConsumer { println("~~~$name~~~") })
  )
  // output:
  // ~~~hello~~~
  // true
}
```

Now there's no ambiguity about the return type - the `use(...)` functions either accept a predicate or consumer, end of story.

Note: `with(block) { ... }` ([read more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65376089/4161471)) is required because the functional interfaces we've defined have receivers.

#### Generics + Functional interfaces

We can combine the two to get the best of both worlds: succinctness and clarity:

```kotlin
// define a generic fun-interface
fun interface ContextFunction<R> {
  // change Context to be a parameter, not a receiver 
  fun execute(context: Context): R
}

class ContextService(
  private val context: Context
) {
  
  // use our generic fun-interface
  fun <R> use(block: ContextFunction<R>): Boolean {
    
    return when (val result = block.execute(context)) {
      // if the result isn't a boolean, then the default response is 'true'
      !is Boolean -> true
      // else, we can use the actual result
      else        -> result
    }
  }
}

// usage is the same as 'Option 1: Generics'
fun main() {
  val service = ContextService(Context("hello"))

  println(
    service.use { it.name == "hello" }
  )
  // output: true

  println(
    service.use { it.name == "good morning" }
  )
  // output: false

  println(
    service.use { println("~~~${it.name}~~~") }
  )
  // output:
  // ~~~hello~~~
  // true
}
```